# Reset array keys in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I've been looking around for a solution to this with no real success. I have a multidimensional array of parents and children with no limits on depth. This is generated from a database but the issue is that the item ID becomes the key using my way of arranging a flat array into a multidimensional array like so:

```
Array(

[28] => Array
        (
            [id] => 28
            [color] => #ff24e5
            [name] => Personal
            [parent_id] => 
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [23] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 23
                            [color] => #41c3a3
                            [name] => Shopping
                            [parent_id] => 28
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [22] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 22
                                            [color] => #8be32b
                                            [name] => Deals
                                            [parent_id] => 23
                                            [children] => Array
                                                (
                                                )
                                        )
                                )
                        )

                    [150] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 150
                            [color] => #e9a3f0
                            [name] => Orders
                            [parent_id] => 28
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

What I would like, is a function that does the following:

```
Array (
[0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 28
            [color] => #ff24e5
            [name] => Personal
            [parent_id] => 
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 23
                            [color] => #41c3a3
                            [name] => Shopping
                            [parent_id] => 28
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 22
                                            [color] => #8be32b
                                            [name] => Deals
                                            [user_id] => 1
                                            [selected] => 0
                                            [parent_id] => 23
                                            [children] => Array
                                                (
                                                )
                                        )
                                )
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 150
                            [color] => #e9a3f0
                            [name] => Orders
                            [parent_id] => 28
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Essentially reassign keys starting from 0. I've tried numerous methods, but I'm assuming that I need to find a recursive solution and when I tried that, it destroyed my array. I was reading up on the array_walk_recursive() function, but I don't quite know what to do beyond that. Essentially, is there a way to reset numeric keys in a multidimensional array?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I answered your question just after you asked it. It's 2 hours later, are you going to return? If this answered your question, please click the checkmark icon next to the answer to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
function fix_keys($array) {
  foreach ($array as $k => $val) {
    if (is_array($val)) 
      $array[$k] = fix_keys($val); //recurse
  }
  return array_values($array);
}
```

Comment: Great! Thanks. Didn't get an email, so I only checked now.

Comment: This works but I am losing the array keys that are not numerical, how would I go about only reassigning numerical keys? Thanks

Answer (score 21):

You really need to add the is_numeric condition to stop text keys getting mixed up...

```
function fix_keys($array) {

    foreach ($array as $k => $val) {

        if (is_array($val)) 
            $array[$k] = $fix_keys($val); //recurse
    }

    if( is_numeric($k) )
        return array_values($array);

    return $array;
}
```

I did this instead:

```
function fix_keys($array) {
    $numberCheck = false;
    foreach ($array as $k => $val) {
        if (is_array($val)) $array[$k] = fix_keys($val); //recurse
        if (is_numeric($k)) $numberCheck = true;
    }
    if ($numberCheck === true) {
        return array_values($array);
    } else {
        return $array;
    }
}
```

Comment: Fantastic! This worked brilliantly for me, whereas the current correct answer did not.

Answer (score 12):

I was trying to fix the same problem, here is the code

```
$array = array_values($array);
```

Comment: This won't work for multi-dimensional arrays. The fix_keys() function above will work. https://3v4l.org/vGmmJ

Answer (score 1):

the correct answer reset all keys and dont ignore the not numeric keys, "Lobos" answer is a step in the right direction, but reset too the not numeric keys by level 2 and lower.
for me this done the job perfect

```
function array_values_recursive($array) {
$temp = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (is_numeric($key)) {
        $temp[] = is_array($value) ? array_values_recursive($value) : $value;
    } else {
        $temp[$key] = is_array($value) ? array_values_recursive($value) : $value;
    }
}
return $temp;
```

}