# Hierarchical data to array

Tags: php

I've been searching for this for some days but cant seem to find the anwer.
I have an array like

```
$startArray = Array(array('name' => 'A', 'hierarchy' => '1'),
    array('name' => 'B', 'hierarchy' => '1.2'),
    array('name' => 'C', 'hierarchy' => '1.3'),
    array('name' => 'D', 'hierarchy' => '1.3.1')
);
```

and i would like to go to

```
$endResult = 
    array(
          array('name' => 'A', 
            'children' => array(
               array('name'=> 'b'), 
               array('name'=> 'c', 
                 'children' => array('name' => 'D')
               )
            )
    );
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: Do you want to convert your first array to be the second array? Please be more specific what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Your "expected result" is incorrect, as `'name'=>'b','name'=>'c'` will only results in `'name'=>'c'`. Did you mean `array(array('name'=>'b'),array('name'=>'c','children'=>array(...)))`?

Comment: You are right, i clearly jotted it down to quickly. I improved the question, I hope it understandable now? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay here is a long solution, which you might want to wrap into a function, perhaps. Just copy and paste this inside a blank document and check the result in a browser.

```
<pre>
<?php

    $orig = array(
        array('name' => 'A', 'hierarchy' => '1'),
        array('name' => 'B', 'hierarchy' => '1.2'),
        array('name' => 'C', 'hierarchy' => '1.3'),
        array('name' => 'D', 'hierarchy' => '1.3.1')
        //,array('name' => 'E', 'hierarchy' => '1.2.1')
        //,array('name' => 'F', 'hierarchy' => '2.1')
    );

    function special_sort($arr1,$arr2) {
        $h1 = $arr1['hierarchy'];
        $h2 = $arr2['hierarchy'];
        $ch1 = count($h1);
        $ch2 = count($h2);
        if ($ch1 < $ch2) return -1;
        if ($ch1 > $ch2) return 1;
        return $h1 > $h2 ? 1 : ($h1 < $h2 ? -1 : 0);
    }
    // this first checks lengths and then values
    // so 1.3 gets -1 against 1.2.1 whereas
    // 1.3.2 still gets 1 against 1.3.1

    $temp = $orig;
    // temporary array to keep your original untouched
    foreach ($temp as &$arr) {
        $arr['hierarchy'] = explode('.',$arr['hierarchy']);
        // turn hierachy numbers into arrays for later
        // sorting purposes
    }
    unset($arr);
    // get rid of the reference used in the loop
    usort($temp,'special_sort');
    // sort by the sort function above

    echo '<h2>$orig</h2>'; print_r($orig);
    echo '<h2>$temp</h2>'; print_r($temp);
    // for you to see what it looks like now

    $res = array();
    // our final array

    // by the following loop we're using the hierarcy
    // numbers as keys to push into the result array
    foreach ($temp as $arr) {
        $h = $arr['hierarchy'];
        if (count($h) == 1) {
        // this is for those with single hierarchy
        // numbers such as 1, 2, etc.
            $res[$h[0]] = array('name'=>$arr['name']);
            continue;
        }
        if (!isset($res[$h[0]]))
            $res[$h[0]] = array('name'=>'');
        // if, say this is 2.1 but there is no 2 in the array then
        // we need to create that. see the last commented item in
        // the original array. uncomment it to see why I wrote this
        $newLoc =& $res[$h[0]];
        // reference of the new place in result
        // array to push the item
        for ($i = 1; $i < count($h); $i++) {
            if (!isset($newLoc['children']))
                $newLoc['children'] = array();
            // create children array if it doesn't exist
            if (!isset($newLoc['children'][$h[$i]]))
                $newLoc['children'][$h[$i]] = array();
            // create children[hierarch key] array if it doesn't exist
            $newLoc =& $newLoc['children'][$h[$i]];
            // update reference
        }
        $newLoc = array('name'=>$arr['name']);
        // assign the new name to this reference
        unset($newLoc);
        // get rid of the reference
    }

    unset($temp);
    // get rid of the array now that we're done with it

    echo '<h2>$res</h2>'; print_r($res);

    function fix_keys($array) {
        foreach ($array as $k => $val) {
            if (is_array($val)) $array[$k] = fix_keys($val);
        }
        if(is_numeric($k)) return array_values($array);
        return $array;
    }
    // function courtesy of Lobos,
    // http://stackoverflow.com/a/12399408/913097

    $endRes = fix_keys($res);
    // create the end result array. this is actually
    // a copy of the $res array except the numeric
    // keys were reset.

    unset($res);
    // get rid of the last unused array

    echo '<h2>$endRes</h2>'; print_r($endRes);

?>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

you do not have the correct array, the values ​​will be rewritten. You need approximately the:

```
$arr = array(
  array('name' => 'a', 'hierarchy' => '1'),
  array('name' => 'b', 'hierarchy' => '1.2'),
);
```