# json_encode() on a multidimensional array - with string keys

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, json

I am creating an very large multidimensional array using PHP. Each object contains Name, ID, ParentID and Children. Children is an array of more objects in the same format.

It is critical I name the IDs of each object - this helps me put each object under the correct parent. (In the code below, I use 101, 102 etc.)

However, the problem I am having is when I return the array in JSON using `json_encode`. Each 'Children' array is being printed as an object, not an array - as shown in the JSON code below.

As I read on another SO thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10778760/1359306), they "are made as objects because of the inclusion of string keys" - although they are numbers, they are still strings.

```
{
"101": {
    "ID": "101",
    "ParentID": "0",
    "Name": "Root One"
    "Children": {
        "102": {
            "ID": "102",
            "ParentID": "101",
            "Name": "Child One"
        },
        "103": {
            "ID": "103",
            "ParentID": "101",
            "Name": "Child Two",
            "Children": {
                "104": {
                    "ID": "104",
                    "ParentID": "103",
                    "Name": "Child Child One"
                }
            }
        },
```

Does anyone know how to overcome this issue?

**Edit:** The JSON should look like this (the square brackets are important!):

```
[
{
    "ID": "101",
    "ParentID": "0",
    "Name": "Root One",
    "Children": [
        {
            "ID": "102",
            "ParentID": "101",
            "Name": "Child One",
            "Children": [
```

Comment: It's actually because the indices are not contiguous, i.e. there are gaps.

Comment: Also, your "children" ARE objects (from my perspective) and not arrays. Be glad, and let OOP flow within you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have now got a working solution which is fast and works well.

1. Firstly, as written in SO link from the question;

   > In JSON, arrays only have numeric keys, whereas objects have string
   >   properties. The inclusion of a array key forces the entire outer
   >   structure to be an object by necessity.

   In JSON; Curly braces hold objects (`{}`), Square brackets hold arrays (`[]`).
2. So using a string as a key will result in the `json_encode` function returning objects, whereas reseting the keys will ensure it creates arrays.
3. Therefore, just before I return my JSON encoded string, I run a function to reset all the array keys. The code I found on this SO thread [(Reset array keys in multidimensional array)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12399408/1359306) was particularly useful!

Answer (score 6):

A JSON array has no explicit indexes, it's just an *ordered list*. The only JSON data structure that has *named keys* is an object. The literal should make this quite obvious:

```
["foo", "bar", "baz"]
```

This *array* has no named indices and there isn't any provision to add any.

PHP conflates both lists and key-value stores into one `array` data type. JSON doesn't.

Comment: associative array has  named keys

Comment: @mohammad ***PHP*** has "associative arrays", ***JSON*** doesn't! JSON's "associative arrays" are called *objects*.

Comment: Thanks, the issue I was having was the structure of the JSON (see my last edit). The problem was caused due to the named keys in my PHP associative array.

Answer (score 3):

This is your object:

```
$parent=new StdClass();
$parent->ID=101;
$parent->ParentID=0;
$parent->Name='Root One';

$child1=new StdClass();
$child1->ID=1011;
$child1->ParentID=$parent->ID;
$child1->Name='Child One';
$parent->Children[]=$child1;


$child1_1=new StdClass();
$child1_1->ID=10111;
$child1_1->ParentID=$child1->ID;
$child1_1->Name='Child One One';
$child1->Children[]=$child1_1;
```

This is your JSON convert function:

```
echo json_encode($parent,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

and this is your object coded into JSON format:

```
{
    "ID": 101,
    "ParentID": 0,
    "Name": "Root One",
    "Children": [
        {
            "ID": 1011,
            "ParentID": 101,
            "Name": "Child One",
            "Children": [
                {
                    "ID": 10111,
                    "ParentID": 1011,
                    "Name": "Child One One"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The answer came later because I started learning PHP later. Anyway, some day, someone might find it useful.

Answer (score -2):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Set 2nd parameter of json_decode to true to atleast get assoc arrays.

Aside from that: javascript can't handle non-sequential/non-contiguous array indexes, so as soon as the id's are not sequential, json has no other option then to convert it into "string" indexes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it will no doubt be of use in the future, but I was using the returned JSON in jQuery!

Comment: That hardly changes the fact that javascript can't handle non sequential array keys. Hence neither can JSON. And hence neither can jquery.

Comment: A downvote without comment 1 year after this post.. one wonders why o.O