# PHP json_encode string key as array

Tags: php, json

i write a api for my games to get achievements and so on. i load the data from a webserver into unity c# over a www request. i need a array from php which contain achievements and more data. the problem is, the result is this

```
[
    {"ID":"1",
    "gameID":"1",
    "name":"achv1",
    "neededvalue":"50",
    "player_achievements":{
        "ID":"8",
        "achievementID":"1",
        "playerID":"9",
        "value":"",
        "completed":""
        }
    },
    {"ID":"2",
    "gameID": "1",
    "name":"achv2",
    "neededvalue":"100",
    "player_achievements":{
        "ID":"9",
        "achievementID":"2",
        "playerID":"9",
        "value":"","completed":""
        }
    }
]
```

the player_achievements is a child array of the head array and i need the square_brackets around the player_achievements [] because untity c# cannot convert it to an object. i search hours for finding a solution but nobody explain how. i found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16419689/json-encode-on-a-multidimensional-array-with-string-keys) but this is not a option for me. i want the string keys and not numbers. give it a way to use the string keys as array and not as object ?
i need it like so:

```
[
    {   "ID":"1",
        "gameID":"1",
        "name":"achv1",
        "neededvalue":"50",
        "player_achievements":[
            {   "ID":"8",
                "achievementID":"1",
                "playerID":"9",
                "value":"",
                "completed":""
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "ID":"2",
        "gameID":"1",
        "name":"achv2",
        "neededvalue":"100",
        "player_achievements":[
            {   "ID":"9",
                "achievementID":"2",    
                "playerID":"9",
                "value":"",
                "completed":""  
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: So make `player_achievements` an array of objects?

Comment: [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) with the array flag?

Comment: @Jeff they lost one nesting level, it's not a serialisation format problem

Comment: The problem is with the array that you're passing to `json_encode()`. If you show the code that creates it, we can help you fix its structure.

Comment: might wanna json_decode() then json_encode() your data. this has helped me fix alot of JSON issues.

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading your question correctly, you need to make the *player_achievements* element an array containing the original value of that element.

```
<?php

$json = <<<END
[
    {"ID":"1",
    "gameID":"1",
    "name":"achv1",
    "neededvalue":"50",
    "player_achievements":{
        "ID":"8",
        "achievementID":"1",
        "playerID":"9",
        "value":"",
        "completed":""
        }
    },
    {"ID":"2",
    "gameID": "1",
    "name":"achv2",
    "neededvalue":"100",
    "player_achievements":{
        "ID":"9",
        "achievementID":"2",
        "playerID":"9",
        "value":"","completed":""
        }
    }
]
END;

$data = json_decode($json, true);

for($i=0;$i<sizeof($data);$i++)
{
    $data[$i]['player_achievements'] = [$data[$i]['player_achievements']];
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

This produces a structure like the one you say you need.

```
[
  {
    "ID": "1",
    "gameID": "1",
    "name": "achv1",
    "neededvalue": "50",
    "player_achievements": [
      {
        "ID": "8",
        "achievementID": "1",
        "playerID": "9",
        "value": "",
        "completed": ""
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "ID": "2",
    "gameID": "1",
    "name": "achv2",
    "neededvalue": "100",
    "player_achievements": [
      {
        "ID": "9",
        "achievementID": "2",
        "playerID": "9",
        "value": "",
        "completed": ""
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score -2):

I found an answer, I add a zero before the child element as key of array.