# Splitting array while reseting only key index

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, indexing

( feel free to jump to the **TL;DR** version below..

I have an array of RGB values form an image of 62x62 pixels. ( thats 3844 elements ).

```
   [$ard_array]

    Array ( [0] => leds[1] = CRGB(127,204,53) 
            [1] => leds[2] = CRGB(100,216,32) 
            [2] => leds[3] = CRGB(79,231,22)
            [3] => leds[4] = CRGB(79,231,22) 
            ....
            ....
            [3843] => leds[3844] = CRGB(255,255,255)
            )
```

Now, I would like to split this array into the the actual columns representation of the image ( each array one column ) , so :

```
$ard_split = (array_chunk($ard_array, 62));
    foreach ( $ard_split as $element ){
    $element = array_values($element);
    // $element = fix_keys($element);
    print_r($element );
    }
```

( [fix_keys() from here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6990970/1244126) )
which gives me

```
Array ( [0] => leds[1] = CRGB(127,204,53) 
    [1] => leds[2] = CRGB(100,216,32)
    [2] => leds[3] = CRGB(79,231,22) 
    [3] => leds[4] = CRGB(69,240,19)
     ...
     ...
    [61] => leds[62] = CRGB(202,251,191)
)
```

but the next one is :

```
Array ( [0] => leds[63] = CRGB(127,204,53) 
        [1] => leds[64] = CRGB(100,216,32)
        [2] => leds[65] = CRGB(79,231,22) 
        [3] => leds[66] = CRGB(69,240,19)
     ...
     ...
    [61] => leds[124] = CRGB(202,251,191)
)
```

So the array index is reset , but I need to reset also the Elements .
I have tried the function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6990970/1244126) as well as others I have found - but no luck.

what I really need two different options :

**1 -** to start a so called `"new array"` for each chunk like so :

```
Array ( [0] => leds[1] = CRGB(127,204,53) 
        [1] => leds[2] = CRGB(100,216,32) 
        [2] => leds[3] = CRGB(79,231,22)
        [3] => leds[4] = CRGB(79,231,22) 
        ....
        ....
        [61] => leds[62] = CRGB(255,255,255)
            )

( repeat same array structure different values )

Array ( [0] => leds[1] = CRGB(127,11,53) 
        [1] => leds[2] = CRGB(141,216,32) 
        [2] => leds[3] = CRGB(179,22,54)
        [3] => leds[4] = CRGB(79,231,22) 
        ....
        ....
        [61] => leds[62] = CRGB(255,255,255)
            )
```

And **2 -** to reset ONLY the array KEYS index, leaving the main index intact like so :

```
Array ( [0] => leds[1] = CRGB(127,11,53) 
        [1] => leds[2] = CRGB(141,216,32) 
        [2] => leds[3] = CRGB(179,22,54)
        [3] => leds[4] = CRGB(79,231,22) 
        ....
        ....
        [61] => leds[62] = CRGB(255,255,255)
            )
Array ( [62] => leds[1] = CRGB(127,11,53) 
        [63] => leds[2] = CRGB(141,216,32) 
        [64] => leds[3] = CRGB(179,22,54)
        [65] => leds[4] = CRGB(79,231,22) 
        ....
        ....
        [124] => leds[62] = CRGB(255,255,255)
            )
```

**Technical bonus question** : this function seems to be very heavy on memory ( not to mention the function that creates this array from GD ) - so would it be better to split this array at to 62 iterations loop the source ( while building it ) or split the full outcome array (62x62 = 3844 ) ??

**TL;DR version:**

While dealing with multidimentional array, I would like to know how to split a large array into chunks while reseting ( ONLY or/and ALSO ) the array keys index.

Comment: I think I'd have an easier time understanding the requirements with a ready-to-go [mcve].